# MySQL: Shortest ways to get from A to B

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know the top n shortest paths (in this example: top 2) from John to Jane while having both values as input values.

A restriction: paths are recognized exclusively from left to right. That means that if there is a path `John -> Pete`, it doesn't mean that there is also a path `Pete -> John`. I have no concrete use case, but I have been wondering for some time how this can be realized.

I'm running MySQL 5x, but would also be grateful for a solution for MySQL 8x.

The setup is

```sql
CREATE TABLE `player` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `path` (
  `left_player_id` int NOT NULL,
  `right_player_id` int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `path` ADD INDEX `left_to_right` (left_player_id, right_player_id);
ALTER TABLE `path` ADD INDEX `right_to_left` (right_player_id, left_player_id);

INSERT INTO player VALUES (1, 'John'),(2, 'Pete'),(3, 'Mike'),(4, 'Jane'),(5, 'Emily'),(6, 'Lily'),(7, 'Abigail'),(8, 'Olivia');

-- John -> Pete, Pete -> Mike, Mike -> Jane.
INSERT INTO path VALUES (1,2),(2,3),(3,4);

-- Pete -> Mike, Mike -> Pete, Mike -> John, John -> Olivia, Olivia -> Emily, Emily -> Abigail, Abigail -> Lily, Lily -> Jane
INSERT INTO path VALUES (2,3),(3,2),(3,1),(1,8),(8,5),(5,7),(7,6),(6,4);
```

What I can imagine is an ascending order as a result, with the shortest path at the top of the list.

```
| path | id |   name  |
|:----:|:--:|:-------:|
|   1  |  1 |   John  |
|   1  |  2 |   Pete  |
|   1  |  3 |   Mike  |
|   1  |  4 |   Jane  |
|   2  |  1 |   John  |
|   2  |  2 |  Olivia |
|   2  |  3 |  Emily  |
|   2  |  4 | Abigail |
|   2  |  5 |   Lily  |
|   2  |  6 |   Jane  |
```

Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c50fa

If you have more suitable software recommendations, which can also handle somewhat larger amounts of data (xx GB, millions of entries in table path), then mention that.

Comment: Define 'fastest' - but I have to warn you, this isn't what SQL is particularly good at.

Comment: For a single query, this requires a recursive or hierarchical query.  MySQL only supports this functionality starting in 8+.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you have? 5.x or 8.x? As Gordon says you'll need 8.x

Comment: I have edited the initial post. I'm running MySQL 5x, but a solution for MySQL 8x would also be fine. Which database or software is performant for such a problem?